# Критика чистого js

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Друзья, покритикуйте пожалуйста [код](http://prozaik.16mb.com/works/pr_proto/carousel_handmade_1_1_js_full/), он писался для тренировки. Условия следующие:

1. Максимальная структурированость кода с расчётом на то, что проект будет поддерживаться много лет и очень часто дорабатываться разными участниками.
2. Проект высоконагруженный и поэтому использование библиотек типа jquery, mootools и т.д. не допускается.

Буду благодарен за советы, которые помогут сделать код и стиль понятнее и рациональнее

Даже если не можете предложить что конкретно исправить, но видите слабое место, то всё равно скажите — я сам подумаю что можно сделать.

```
// ------------ PLUGIN kalininCarousel INITIALIZATION ------------
var kalininCarousel = new KalininCarousel({
    carouselWrap: document.getElementById('carousel_wrap'),
    offsetElements: 0,
    autoScroll: false,
    effectSpeed: 300,
    autoScrollSpeed: 1000,
    arrowsType: 'auto', //'visible', 'hidden', 'auto'
    rotateBy: 1
});
/* 
    INFO: 
    project: kalininCarousel
    browsers: opera/chrome/FF/ie9/safari
    coding: Sergey Kalinin 07/2013 (prozaik81-2@yandex.ru)
    desc: графический компонент для преобразования списка в карусель с возможностью прокрутки при помощи стрелок-указателей. слайды карусели должны быть одинаковой длины
    version 1.1
*/

// ------------ PLUGIN kalininCarousel IMPLEMENTATION ------------
function KalininCarousel(options) {
    // --------- properties ---------   
    var carouselWrap = options.carouselWrap,
        carousel = document.getElementById('carousel'),
        wrapperElements = carousel.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
        carouselElements = wrapperElements.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        carouselElementsWidth;
    if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        carouselElementsWidth = carouselElements[0].offsetWidth
                                + parseInt(getComputedStyle(carouselElements[0], '').marginLeft, 10)
                                + parseInt(getComputedStyle(carouselElements[0], '').marginRight, 10);
    }
    else {
        carouselElementsWidth = carouselElements[0].offsetWidth
                                + parseInt(carouselElements[0].currentStyle.marginLeft, 10)
                                + parseInt(carouselElements[0].currentStyle.marginRight, 10);
    }

    var carouselLength = carouselElements.length,
        running = false,
        autoScroll = 0,
        prev,
        next;

    init();

    // --------- methods ---------  
    function init() {
        wrapperElements.style.width = carouselElementsWidth * carouselLength * 2 + 'px';

        prev = prepend(carouselWrap, 'div');
        prev.id = 'prev';
        prev.className = 'prev';

        next = prepend(carouselWrap, 'div');
        next.id = 'next';
        next.className = 'next';


        if ((options.arrowsType == 'auto') || (options.arrowsType == 'hidden')) {
            toggleControls('none', 'none');
        }

        setIntervalAutoScroll();
    }

    function shift(direction) {
        var offset,
            cloneSlides,
            lastSlide,
            i;

        if (!running) {
            running = true;

            if (options.autoScroll) {
                window.clearInterval(autoScroll);
            }

            if (direction == -1) {
                offset = (carouselElementsWidth * options.rotateBy * direction);

                for (i = 0; i < options.rotateBy; i++) {
                    cloneSlides = carouselElements[i].cloneNode(true);

                    wrapperElements.appendChild(cloneSlides);
                }

                shiftAction();
            }
            else {
                offset = 0;

                for (i = (carouselLength - 1) ; i > (carouselLength - options.rotateBy - 1) ; i--) {
                    cloneSlides = carouselElements[carouselLength - 1].cloneNode(true);

                    wrapperElements.insertBefore(cloneSlides, wrapperElements.firstChild);
                }

                wrapperElements.style.left = (-1 * options.rotateBy * carouselElementsWidth) + 'px';

                shiftAction();
            }
        }

        function shiftAction() {
            var interval,
                offset;

            if (direction == -1) {
                offset = 0;

                function animateLeft() {
                    offset -= 13;

                    wrapperElements.style.left = offset + 'px';

                    if (offset <= (-1 * options.rotateBy * carouselElementsWidth)) {
                        clearInterval(interval);

                        for (i = 0; i < options.rotateBy; i++) {
                            wrapperElements.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0]);
                        }

                        wrapperElements.style.left = 0;

                        running = false;
                    }
                }

                setIntervalCustom(animateLeft);
            }
            else {
                offset = parseInt(wrapperElements.style.left, 10);

                function animateRight() {
                    offset += 13;

                    wrapperElements.style.left = offset + 'px';

                    if (offset >= 0) {
                        clearInterval(interval);

                        for (i = options.rotateBy; i > 0; i--) {
                            wrapperElements.removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('li')[carouselLength + i - 1]);
                        }

                        wrapperElements.style.left = 0;

                        running = false;
                    }
                }

                setIntervalCustom(animateRight);

            }

            function setIntervalCustom(animate) {
                return interval = setInterval(animate, 25);
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleControls(prevState, nextState) {
        prev.style.display = prevState;

        next.style.display = nextState;
    }

    function prepend(id, tag) {
        var first = id.firstChild,
            newNode = document.createElement(tag);

        id.insertBefore(newNode, first);

        return newNode;
    }

    function setIntervalAutoScroll() {
        if (options.autoScroll) {
            autoScroll = window.setInterval(function () {
                shift(-1);
            }, options.autoScrollSpeed);
        }
    }

    function addEvent(elem, type, handler) {
        if (elem.addEventListener) {
            elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
        }
        else {
            elem.attachEvent('on' + type, handler);
        }
    }

    // --------- handlers ---------     
    function onClickControls(direction) {
        shift(direction);
    }

    function onHoverWrap() {
        if (options.arrowsType == 'auto') {
            toggleControls('block', 'block');
        }
    }

    function onLeaveWrap() {
        if (options.arrowsType == 'auto') {
            toggleControls('none', 'none');
        }
    }

    // --------- events ---------   
    addEvent(prev, 'click', function (e) {
        onClickControls(-1);
    }, false);

    addEvent(next, 'click', function (e) {
        onClickControls(1);
    }, false);

    addEvent(carouselWrap, 'mouseover', function (e) {
        onHoverWrap();
    }, false);

    addEvent(carouselWrap, 'mouseleave', function (e) {
        onLeaveWrap();
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: а jquery действительно так сильно влияет на производительность? я думаю у Вас в основном на сервере будет проблемы? а не на клиенте.

в хроме красные квадратики один раз появляются и больше не пропадают. в фаерфоксе - пропадают.

Comment: Если производительность и правда важна, надо думать не о том, использовать jQuery или нет, а о том, использовать javascript или C.

Comment: @VladD Вы это об чём? C на стороне клиента? Или писать клиента вместо браузера? Если браузер нужен, то следует подумать о распределении работы между сервером и клиентом.

Comment: @alexlz: ТС говорит, что вследствие высоконагруженного проекта требуется чистый js вместо связки js + jQuery. Где бы _это_ не бежало, если есть настолько серьёзные проблемы в производительности, стоит подумать о смене платформы.

Comment: @VladD ну да, при таких проблемах это, вероятно, лучший вариант. А насчёт платформы -- могу посоветовать Люберецкую.

Comment: @alexlz: (_озадаченно_) думаете, там помогут?

Comment: @VladD боюсь, что только там и могут помочь.

Comment: код не должен быть на вашем сайте, код должен быть **здесь**

Comment: кроме того, как производительность клиентского софта влияет на  высоконагруженность сервера ? Кроме того, поддерживать много лет  многими сменяющимися людьми намного проще с использованием популярных библиотек. А оптимизация карусели, таким способом вообще странная идея. У вас их на одной странице будет 10000 одновременно крутящихся ?

Comment: Мдя, что за глупости спрашивать «покритиковать» код? Бред же!

И карусель у вас отвратная — скачайте лучше готовый жиКвери-плагин — будет в сто раз красивее код и сама карусель и структурированнее будет в 10 раз, да еще с бесплатными обновлениями и багфиксами от комьюнити.

И не нужно постить сюда тонны кода — есть же http://jsfiddle.net!

Comment: будет красивее и быстрее, но как я указал в первом посте(чтобы не было недопонимания) код писался для тренировки в чистом js. сейчас много любителей использовать готовые решения, но они(готовые решения) в определенном смысле вредны. 

ваш темперамент выдаёт ваш возраст.

культура кода это далеко не глупости. и вопрос вполне в формате этого сайта. вы наверное ни разу не работали с большими проектами

Comment: Работал и работаю и о структуре и культуре знаю. Ну я так и понял, что вы не ЖС-программист, а, скажем, бэкенд-программист и решили что-то на ЖС написать. Лучше отдайте фронтендеру задачу, он её решит лучше. Готовые решения вредны, но только в определенном смысле ;) Но они, по крайней мере, уже протестированы на многих сайтах кучей разработчиков — можете им смело доверять (хотя меня просто бесят все эти плагины — по возможности пишу своё решение).

Comment: @eicto, смотря какой код и какой вопрос, для вопроса имхо даже этот код великоват...

Comment: Бггг, весело, понабежали нубы, поминусовать. Противники жсфидла тоже понабежали. Улыбаюсь.

Comment: я не минусовал, но ваш ответ должен быть в комментарии,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мельком посмотрел код, в глаза бросились несколько моментов:

**Настройки карусели**

Не увидел у Вас стандартных настроек для быстрого запуска карусели например с указанием одного лишь `id` элемента на странице. Думаю имеет смысл их добавить.

---

**Создание карусели. привязка к DOM элементам**

У Вас идет привязка карусели к конкретным элементам на странице, в частности элементу с `id="carousel"`. Также Вы всегда исходите из того, что карусель будет создана на основе `ul`. Как на счет нескольких каруселей на странице? Рекомендую дать возможность задавать через настройки какой элемент является каруселью, какие теги являются элементами итд.

---

**Структура кода**

Мне кажется имеет смысл вынести в отдельные методы получение ширины элемента (строки 19-28) и установку `css` свойств (аналог функции `css` в jquery). Это сделает код более читабельным.

Определите значения для таких вещей как тип отображения стрелок и направление ротации, в отдельные константы и используйте их в коде, а не сами значения напрямую. `(DIRECTION_LEFT/RIGHT, ARROW_TYPE_HIDDEN/VISIBLE/AUTO)`

Comment: плюс дублирование кода в shift() идет.

Comment: определить константы типа DIRECTION_LEFT/RIGHT я сначала хотел, но потом подумал, что это лишняя операция будет. почему бы сразу не использовать options.arrowsType ? думаю, это и быстрее, и программисту запоминать лишнего не нужно. нет?...

от дублирования в shift() не получилось избавиться. была мысль вынести в отдельный метод, но там настолько разный код, что я растерялся. если кто-нибудь хотя бы приблизительным кодом поможет, то буду благодарен

Comment: Ну, о константах Вы судите зная свой код. Я вот не смог сразу сказать что означет условие `direction == -1`. А Вы в свою очередь сказали, что код будет поддерживаться разными людьми.

Comment: спасибо. действительно нужно исправить